# Invalid rank specifier

Tags: xna, xna-4.0

I am trying to create a dungeon crawler with a tile-based map. However, I get an error when creating the array of tiles. (Right now, `Tile` is a class with nothing but an empty constructor.)

```
class Map
{
    Tile[][] Tiles;
    static const int DefaultWidth = 640, DefaultHeight = 480;
    Random rnd;

    public Map(int? Width, int? Height, int? seed)
    {
        Tiles = new Tile[((Width == null) ? DefaultWidth : (int)Width)]
        //This line gives the error "invalid rank specifier: expected ',' or ']'" after the first bracket
            [((Height == null) ? DefaultHeight : (int)Height)];
        Generate();
    }

    void Generate()
    {

    }
}
```

Why am I getting this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In C#, the right way to instantiate a 2D array is to use a comma instead:

`int[,] array = new [3,2];`

You can still make arrays such as `int[][]`, but you'll need to use a for loop to create every individual array inside it (which can be of different lengths), and this is known as a jagged array. I would recommend, however, to use the comma syntax as it is idiomatic in C# and is the expected way to do things.

Comment: Even my programming teacher couldn't tell me that. I guess he works more often in C++ than C#, though.

Comment: What does `int[][]` signify, then? Is it an array of arrays?

Comment: That would be known as a jagged array, because each array inside it can be of different length. Take this for example:

`int[][] array = new int[3][];
            for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
                array[i] = new int[i + 1];` 

In this example, `array[0]` holds an array with 1 element, `array[1]` holds an array with 2 elements, and so on. So you have this idea:
[0] = x
[1] = xx
[2] = xxx